# Is there any legal mechanism in any country, that prevents a state to apply laws discriminatorily?

Tags: criminal-law

As I was explained in another question in this SE community, prosecutors dont have the resources to prosecute every single crime [Does a prosecutor have any legal resource..](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23984/does-a-prosecutor-have-any-legal-resource-to-avoid-aplying-a-law-which-is-uncons)

Then, what does it prevent a state to prosecute people discriminatorily as it might and it indeed happens in certain countries (based in race, sex, political affiliation, etc)?  Is there any legal mechanism in any country, that prevents a state to apply laws discriminatorily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In the United States, the [Equal Protection Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_Protection_Clause) of the 14th Amendment provides that a state cannot "deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws."

When the amendment was being introduced, Senator Howard said, "It prohibits the hanging of a black man for a crime for which the white man is not to be hanged."

Comment: ... but not the shooting of the black man in the course of his arrest for which a white man isnt shot.

Comment: @DaleM The hard part is proving the motivations.